# Access protected property

Tags: delphi

I have a class that is derived from Tobject. In my class i want to use protected properties of control. Here is my code

```
    type
    THack = class(Tcontrol);

    TMyClass = class(TObject)
    private
      A: string;
      B: string;
      C: string;
      D: string;
    public
      procedure DoSomthing(MyForm: TForm);
    end;

  procedure TMyClass.DoSomthing(MyForm: TForm);
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    for I := 0 to MyForm.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      // I want to read Font property
      showmessage(inttostr(THack(MyForm.Controls[I]).Font.Size));
   end; 
  end;
```

Is there any other way i can access protected properties

Comment: you may want to use the public `Controls` property of the form instead. If you really want to use a `protected` property, inherit from the class which owns the property like this: `TMyClass = class(TControl)` or `TMyClass = class(THack)`

Comment: @fantaghirocco  than to access font property i have to typecase TMyClass(MyForm.Controls[I]).Font.size

Comment: @fantaghirocco - Font is protected inside TControl.

Comment: and than i can access other fields as well Eg TMyClass(MyForm.Controls[I]).A which is wrong

Comment: Do you want to access properties from all the controls on the form or just a specific bunch? If a specific bunch is required then I would propose defining the selection of those controls a bit better. If you know the classes of those controls then you will most probably be able to better control them with proper casting.

Comment: @BlurrySterk yes i want to access only few properties but there is a issue if i derived my class from Tcontrol. I have explained that issue in my previous comment

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: @BlurrySterk  **Font is protected** thank you, I missed that point

Comment: @DavidHeffernan there is nothing wrong with my current approach, i thought maybe there is a better way to implement this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The options that I am aware of that can perform this task are:

1. The classic *protected hack* that is demonstrated in the question.
2. New style RTTI.
3. A class helper.

Comment: Reason we used Helper classes are is to extend the functionality of base class. I am not an expert but do you think using helper class is a correct approach ?

Comment: @RahulBajaj Very hard to give such general advice. Sometimes you might prefer to use the classic hack, sometimes the code might be clearer with a helper. Helpers have downsides too. Only one can be active at any given point in your code. It's really up to you to decide how you want to do this.