# Why the WM_GETFONT doesn't work?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2

Delphi XE2.

For a TForm I do:

```
hFont := SendMessage(Self.Handle, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);
```

But it returns 0. That is, as if the form has a system font. Why is that?

And if I do, for example, like this:

```
hFont := SendMessage(CheckBox1.Handle, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);
```

That returns the correct descriptor.

The same thing, for example, for TPanel - hFont = 0. And for the TButton, the hFont has the correct value.

Comment: Maybe, it is easier to use `Panel1.Font.Handle`? You will always obtain definite value.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But for all components the call is executed `procedure TWinControl.CreateWnd;  
begin  
  ...........
  ...........
  Perform(WM_SETFONT, FFont.Handle, 1);
  ...........
  ...........
end;
`    I checked in a debugger (with debug .dcus)

Comment: @Miamy I pass to my procedure a variable that has a type of TControl.
And the font property of the TControl is protected.

Comment: If you want, [you can still access protected properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222200/access-protected-property).

Answer (score 2):

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140724-00/?p=413

The WM_SET­FONT and WM_GET­FONT messages are not mandatory. A window may choose to support them, or it may choose not to, or it may even choose to support one but not the other. (Though if it supports WM_SET­FONT, it probably ought to support WM_GET­FONT.)

Comment: A system font can return a non zero handle for a static control, here it was negative which may imply other things going on. Interestingly, it becomes zero as soon as any of the [SS styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/static-control-styles) are incorrectly attempted on the control with the font